# What's the proper way to describe hitting the bottom of a staff of rod against the ground?

Tags: single-word-requests

I mean like when a king or something orders silence, he has the staff and/or rod in his hand and hits it against the ground, making the loud clap or boom to get everybody's attention.

Comment: The 'trois coups' that signal the start of a theatrical performance in France are usually translated as _blows_ or _knocks_ (of a staff).

Comment: How is this about anything but style or vocabulary

Answer (score 2):

"Quiet!" shouted the old Man, **thumping** his walking-stick on the ground in front of him.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thump:

> **Thump**:
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1: to strike or beat with or as if with something thick or heavy so as to cause a dull sound
>
> 2: POUND, KNOCK
>
> 3: WHIP, THRASH
>
> 4: to produce (music) mechanically or in a mechanical manner —usually used with outthumped out a tune on the piano
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1a: to inflict a thump
>
> b: to make or move with a thumping sound

And its corresponding noun, the sound that is produced when the staff, sceptre, etc. is *thumped* is:

> **thump**
>
> noun
>
> Definition of thump (Entry 2 of 2)
>
> : a blow or knock with or as if with something blunt or heavy also : the sound made by such a blow

Answer (score 1):

I am no grammarian but I would use 'strike' as it implies an attempt to show authority.

Answer (score 0):

"To hammer/pound the floor with one's staff " is one possibility ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hammer_2).

> ​[intransitive, transitive] to hit something hard many times, especially so that it makes a loud noise 
>   synonym pound
>
> • Someone was hammering at the door.

Comment: I would say "thump".

Comment: reverberating thud of his staff; vicious thud of, crackling strike of, mighty clop, solemn heavy blow of the staff upon the hall's stone floor,